# How to get postion range of a list when give any number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 14, 19], how can i get any number range index.

For example:

```py
l = [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 14, 19]
value = 11

range_index = get_range_index(l)
range_index = (5, 6) # need like this

# give a value = 11, need to get value index like (5, 6), because 10 < value < 14. 
# the list size  may be very very long,can there have good method?
```

This i try to get left value and calculate index by returned left value.
It's not very good and not high performance.

```py
def get_left_point(self, data, value):
    if len(data) == 1:
        return data[0]

    mid_index, mid_value = len(data) // 2, data[len(data) // 2]
    if value >= float(mid_value):
        ret = self.get_left_point(data[mid_index:], value)
    else:
        ret = self.get_left_point(data[:mid_index], value)

    return ret
```

Comment: What do you mean by *any number range index* ?

Comment: Do you check multiple ranges against the same list, or just one?

Comment: update content.

Comment: @HarshAggarwal gived any number and then to get the number range's index.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_range = (100, 101)
[x for x in l if (my_range[0] <= x) and (x <= my_range[1])]
```

Comment: i have update my post, i need to get any value index range

Comment: Ok, that's different. You need to run a modified binary search on your list then. I don't have time to write something up right now but maybe later

Comment: i had write a half method, but it's not high performance, and i try to get left point and then  to get it index later.